# How to auto space things(months) in pgfgantt?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to do Gantt chart in Latex thus I'm studying http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf, where I can do something like:

[image]

by coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,vgrid,time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,time slot unit=month
]{2018-09}{2019-06} \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{2018-09}{2018-10} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 2 - Do something}{2018-11}{2018-12} \\
    \ganttbar{Something else}{2019-01}{2019-02} \\
    \ganttbar{Another task}{2019-03}{2019-4}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

I can change the way month is shown with `\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname}`:

[image]

And it becomes a mess with `\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name}`

[image]

One way to manually space things is `x unit=10mm`:

[image]

How to auto space things?

Comment: Do you mean something like `x unit = width("November")` ?